# Meteor mocha test subscriptions

Tags: mongodb, testing, meteor, mocha.js, subscription

I'm currently working on writing client-side tests for my application using `practicalmeteor:mocha`. Therefor I need to insert a record into a mongo collection before every step.

Following the concepts of meteor, I wrote some meteor methods to insert/update/delete the records. If I want to test the expected behaviour, I assume I have to call the appropiate method *(to insert a record for example)* and then have to wait for the subscription to synchronize the record to the client so I can verify the insert.

I tried a few things but none of them seems to work:

```
describe('a topic', function() {
    beforeEach(async function(done) {
        let res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Meteor.call('topics.createNew', function(err, res) {
                if(err) return reject(err);
                resolve(res); //res is the _id from the generated record
            });
        });

        //subscribe to single record (the one just created)
        let subscription = Meteor.subscribe('topics.details', res); 

        //i assume this runs every time the publish function calls ready and therefor is also run when the new record is published
        Tracker.autorun((computation) => {
            let count = TopicsCollection.find({}).count();
            //console.log('topic count: ' + count);                

            if(subscription.ready() && count === 1) {
                computation.stop();
                done();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I logged the counted documents and had luck when i wrapped the autorun-Funktion into a Promise but in neither of both cases, `done()` was called causing a timeout in mocha.

I already had a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967248/mocha-test-is-not-waiting-for-publication-subscription) but I think it doesnt really help in my situation since I wait for every possible callback and I'm working with a plain Collection and the guy in the question above uses an accounts-package.

Can anyone suggest a better/working solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing your current setup:

- calling a method on the client
- insert some doc on the server
- subscribe to the pub from the client
- verify inserts by the subscribed data

Which is a big blackbox that is on the scope here. Additionally you are testing things, that are already tested by the Meteor core team: integration tests of Methods and Publications between server and client.

To prevent waste of time, you can split up your setup into two tests:

- Test the Meteor method as a unit
- Test the Meteor publication as a unit

If those tests are defining the intended behavior with correct permission levels, you can assume, that if you are a logged in user with the correct permission level subscribing to your publication, that this user will get the resulting behavior as you have tested in the units. As I pointed out before, the pub/sub system should be assumed as 'working' by definition.

**1. Test the method, server side only**

Use [hwillson:stub-collections](https://github.com/hwillson/meteor-stub-collections) to get a 'mock' of your collection, use [practicalmeteor:sinon](https://github.com/practicalmeteor/meteor-sinon) to mock your Meteor.user() object to test different permission levels.

**2. Test the publication, server side only**

Use [johanbrook:publication-collector](https://github.com/johanbrook/meteor-publication-collector) to test if your publication is running correctly and [dburles:factory](https://github.com/versolearning/meteor-factory/) create mocks of your collection's data.

No need then for a complex test setup on the client side.